# How to use a modified local Docker container instead of the earlier version from Docker local registry

Tags: docker, docksal

I have a local Dockerfile, with:

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache:7.2
```

.....
I added some lines in the Dockerfile and build it locally:

```
docker build -t webdevops/php-apache:7.3
```

Now I wan to use the 7.3 version of Docker container.

I am using Docksal (https://docksal.io/) to bring this container and other 3 containers up.
so would this work? and when I execute command `$fin up` on Mac terminal.
it will automatically look for version 7.3 of this container tag, and use it? or do I have to do anything additional?
Just want to confirm, if I don't have to change the:

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache:7.2
```

to

```
webdevops/php-apache:7.3
```

Which, in this case would look locally for version 7.3 and use that instead of 7.2 in the registry.

Adding steps and error results for clarity:

appending the following in Dockerfiles

```
ADD BCPSG.cer /etc/ssl/certs
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

run the command: $docker build -t webdevops/php-apache:7.3 .

Error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mcrypt"
    install failed
    The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

possible fix:

```
FROM php:7.2
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
&& docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

Comment: what's 'Docksal', what's '$fin'? Anyway you build a docker image which is based on _webdevops/php-apache:7.2_ and tag this new image with __webdevops/php-apache:7.3_? Are you the maintainer of the _webdevops_ images? You should tag this with a name of your own

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself rather than asking it here? If you get errors which you cannot resolve then you should ask here

Comment: @deosha i have tested it and added the steps plus the error i am getting, Can the -1 be removed now?

Answer (score 0):

yes it will work you can remove this container and add new container using this docker files. which you have newly created.

```
Docker ps
```

Find particular container name or tag assign to particular container

> Docker rm "containername"

you can also delete all containers using

```
Docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

and after deleting old containers add the new container.

> Docker run -d -p port:containerport imagename:tag